# Reduce Ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, resources, server-side

I'm making a chat script using jQuery and JSON, but my hosting suspends it due to 'resources usage limit'. I want to know if it is possible (and how) to reduce these requests. I read one question in which they tell something about an Ajax timeout, but I'm not very good at Ajax. The code is:

```
function getOnJSON() {
    var from;
    var to;
    var msg_id;
    var msg_txt;
    var new_chat_string;

    //Getting the data from the JSON file
    $.getJSON("/ajax/end.emu.php", function(data) {
        $.each(data.notif, function(i, data) {
            from = data.from;
            to = data.to;
            msg_id = data.id;
            msg_txt = data.text;
            if ($("#chat_" + from + "").length === 0) {
                $("#boxes").append('...some stuf...');
                $('#' + from + '_form').submit(function(){
                    contactForm = $(this);
                    valor = $(this + 'input:text').val();
                    destinatary = $(this + 'input[type=hidden]').val();
                    reponse_id = destinatary + "_input";
                    if (!$(this + 'input:text').val()) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    else {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/ajax/end.emu.php?ajax=true",
                            type: contactForm.attr('method'),
                            data: contactForm.serialize(),
                            success: function(data){
                                responsed = $.trim(data);
                                if (responsed != "success") {
                                    alert("An error occured while posting your message");
                                }
                                else {
                                    $('#' + reponse_id).val("");
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        return false;
                    }
                });

                $('#' + from + '_txt').jScrollPane({
                    stickToBottom: true,
                    maintainPosition: true

                });
                $('body').append('<embed src="http://cdn.live-pin.com/assets/pling.mp3" autostart="true" hidden="true" loop="false">');
            }
            else {
                var pane2api = $('#' + from + '_txt').data('jsp');
                var originalContent = pane2api.getContentPane().html();
                pane2api.getContentPane().append('<li id="' + msg_id + '_txt_msg" class="chat_txt_msg">' + msg_txt + '</li>');
                pane2api.reinitialise();
                pane2api.scrollToBottom();
                $('embed').remove();
                $('body').append('<embed src="http://cdn.live-pin.com/assets/pling.mp3" autostart="true" hidden="true" loop="false">');
            }
        });
    });
}
```

The limit is of 600 reqs/5 min, and I need to make it almost each second. I had a year already paid and they have no refund, also I can't modify the server, just have access to `cPanel`.

Comment: What is a 'resources usage limit' exactly? Too many requests in total? Too much data? Request frequency too high? If too many requests, then maybe look at Web Sockets?

Comment: @PaulGrime limit of 600 requests each 5 minutes in total, trying to get 1 request each second to be almost in real-time. I heard something about some timeouts with AJAX but don't understood, :S

Comment: I'd strongly recommend changing the provider. This is a **very** restrictive restiction

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, 600 req/5 min is pretty restrictive if you want to make a request/sec for each user. Essentially, that gives you that each user will make 60 req/min. Or 300/5 min. In other words, even if you optimize your script to combine the two requests to one, **at maximum you can have two users at your site** ;) Not much I guess...

You have two options:

1. Stick with making a chat system through Ajax requests and change the hosting provider. This might be actually cheaper if you don't have the skills to do 2.
2. Forget about making an Ajax request to poll and potentially another to push every second. Implement something around web sockets, long-polling or even [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol).
   If you go that route, I would look at [socket.io](http://socket.io/) for a transparent library that uses web sockets where they are supported and has fallbacks to long polling and others for the rest. For the XMPP-way, there is the excellent [Strophe.js](http://strophe.im/). Note that both routes are much more complex than your Ajax requests and will require a lot of server logic changes.

Comment: Thanks, I see but it does not only make Chat requests, and a few weeks ago I saw something on internet that you can make one request each 10 minutes

Comment: And keep like a timeout, so if the server gets a new message, it returns and if doesnt, it does a new call, I saw it very quickly so I couldn't know how

Comment: And sorry for posting too much comments, im from a blackberry. Isn't there any other way? Also I dont know if this are 600/5 but for each visitor, due to DDoS and those stuff.

Comment: @Luis Yes, the long poll is exactly that. It starts a request but does not properly end it, while using the channel more or less as a socket. When the request eventually closes, a new one immediately starts. You will not be able to do that with 50 lines of code. You need libraries.

Comment: So to make it more clear, socket.io will use Web Sockets if available, if not it will use what you describe as long requests. As for the 600/5min/visitor that is still way too low. Change you provider anyway, there exist many around that are cheap.

Answer (score 2):

ggozad's response is good, I also recommend web sockets. They work only with newer browser models, so if you want to make it available on all browsers you will need a small Flash bridge (Flash can communicate with sockets very easily and also it can call JavaScript functions and be called from JavaScript). Also, Flash offers P2P if you are interested. http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/

Also, for server side you can look into [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) if you are a JavaScript fan like me :)

To complete my response: there is no way to make an Ajax based chat in witch you are limited to 600 requests/5 min (2 requests/second), want to make a request/second and want more than two users.

Solution: switch to sockets or P2P.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to call that paid service from the server side using a single thread (as an API proxy). You can still poll with 600 requests/5 min in this thread. Then every client do Ajax requests to poll or long-poll to your server API proxy without limitation.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that checking each second is really a good idea, in my opinion for online chat 2/3 seconds check should be far enough.

To get less request, you can also add a check on the user activity in client side, if the windows is inactive you can lengthen the checking time, going back to 2/3 seconds when the user come back active, that will allow you to save resources and requests / minutes

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on a project right now that requires keeping the UI in sync with server events. I've been using long polling which does indeed reduce the number of ajax calls, but then it put's the burden on the server to listen for the event that the client is interested in, which isn't fun either.

I'm about to switch over to socket.io which I will set up as a separate push service.

existing server --> pushes to sockt.io server --> pushes to subscribing client